# CSS-свойство position: fixed

Tags: css

Народ, помогите решить проблемку! Опыта мало, не знаю с какой стороны лучше подойти.

Есть блок со свойством `position: fixed`, в нем может быть различный объем текста.
Когда текста не много - все ок, когда много - блок начинает заползать туда, куда не следует. А если стянуть окно браузера по вертикале, то вообще жара... К тому же если смотреть на айпаде, например, там он еще и по горизонтали плавать начинает.

Собственно сам вопрос - можно ли сделать границы для этого блока, за которые он не мог выезжать?

Ниже добавлю ссылку, чтобы можно было посмотреть как это выглядит (под блоком я имел ввиду матрасика/губку помощника, тот что в левой части сайта)
[ссылка на пример](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81.%D1%80%D1%84/)

Comment: У меня не получилось покорёжить блок по горизонтали, остаётся таким какой есть :)
По вертикали можно жёстко задать max-height и сделать overflow hidden или scroll.

Comment: а можно чуть подробнее, я только учусь ;(

Comment: Для этого блока записать

    #mtr_say {
      max-height: 200px;
      overflow: hidden;  /* или scroll */
    }

Comment: Необходимо видеть сам пример, чтобы понять, как он должен себя вести и куда не должен заезжать. А так очень трудно сказать. Вероятно, что стоит задать 100% высоту и ширину относительно окна, если это, допустим, прослойка под модальное окно.

Answer (score 1):

Может потому что

> position: fixed; bottom: 85px;

а надо

> position: fixed; top: 85px;

Comment: может ерунду писать не будем? 
1. я уже пробовал ))
2. тогда в некоторых случаях заезжает на футер...

Comment: поставте минимальную высоту для тега html, и все будет в порядке,

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
position: fixed;
margin: auto 0 85px;
bottom: 0;
top: 0;
max-height: calc(100vh - 170px);
overflow: auto;
```